# Laravel 5.4 Swift_TransportException: response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

When I try to send an email in production it returns me this error:

> [2017-10-23 18:54:17] local.ERROR: Swift_TransportException: Expected
>   response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501 Invalid
>   command or cannot parse from address " in
>   /var/www/laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383

but same time I have a contact form on this domain and it works fine!

Why is this happening?

I both cases i use :

```
 Mail::to($user->email)->bcc('tokyo@website.jp ')->queue(new BuyerComment($data));
```

This is my .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=*********
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I got it the problem was just in my code!

```
>bcc('tokyo@website.jp ')
```

has to be:

```
>bcc('tokyo@website.jp')
```

A stupid mistake a, space in the end! lol